# How to get "erase to left" icon in UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am trying to get the "erase to left" symbol in the text of an UIButton - but how?

```
⌫   Delete  [Delete]    &#x232B;    U+232B  ERASE TO THE LEFT
```

Or is my only option to make a place a png in the UIButton?

Any ideas? - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the unicode character as the label of the button:

```
[myButton setTitle:@"\u232B" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You may need to play with the font, font size and content insets to get it to look nice.

Comment: Do you mean, so it is a delete to right instead? That's @"\u2326"

Comment: no I mean to have the "box+triangle" filled and the "x" transparent. Like the phone-keypad.

Comment: I think that one is an image, not a symbol. The symbol doesn't have the solid background.